# Searching string in a multiline file using perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to find a match in a multi-line string using this script.
It works only when there's one row in the destination file.
I would like to know if there's any substitution for $_ in order to search a multi-line text?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $time=`date +%D_%H:%M`;
chomp($time);

my $last_location=`cat /file.txt`;
chomp($last_location);

open (ERRORLOG, ">>/errors.log") || die "failed to open errorlog file \n$!\n\a";
open (MESSAGES, "</logfile") || die "failed to open alarms file \n$!\n\a";

seek(MESSAGES, 0, 2) ||  die "Couldn't seek to pos: 0 at end of file $!\n";
$end_position = tell(MESSAGES);

if ($end_position < $last_location) {
    $last_location=0;
}

if ($end_position > $last_location) {
    seek(MESSAGES, $last_location, 0) ||  die "Couldn't seek to pos: $last_location $!    \n";
    $num_of_messages_sent=0;

    while (<MESSAGES>) {
        chomp;
        $line_to_check $_;
        if ($line_to_check =~ /some text/ ) {
            print ERRORLOG "$time: $line_to_check \n";
            if ($num_of_messages_sent < 4) {
                do something;
            }

            if ($num_of_messages_sent == 4) {
                do something;
            }
            #increase counter
            $num_of_messages_sent = $num_of_messages_sent + 1;
        }
    }

    $last_location = tell(MESSAGES);
#        print "last: $last_location   , end: $end_position  \n";
    `echo $last_location >/file_last_location.txt`;
}
close (ERRORLOG);
close (MESSAGES);
```

Comment: Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY script.  That may not be your issue, but you're more likely to get people invested in helping you if you do this basic step to ensure your code is more error free.

Answer (score 1):

Looks better this way:

```
while (my $line = <MESSAGES>) {
  chomp($line);
  print "line : $line\n";
  if ($line =~ m!your_regexp_here!i){
    print ERRORLOG "$time: $line_to_check \n";
    $num_of_messages_sent++;
    print "\tMATCH\tline: $line\n";
    if ($num_of_messages_sent < 4){
      print "Found $num_of_messages_sent matches\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answers. i replaced the while loop with this code. but nothing happend. no errors and no results.